# Semantics with 'section' element

Tags: html, semantics

I have been reading up about the 'section' element, whilst trying to understand how I should be using it in my documents.

In the documentation, I see it states:

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or
>   application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of
>   content. Each section should be identified, typically by including a
>   heading (h1-h6 element) as a child of the section element.

As an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Site Name</title>

</head>

<body>

    <header>

        <div class="container">

            <img src="logo.jpg" srcset="logo.jpg, logo@2x.jpg 2x" title="Site Name" alt="Site Name">

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Page</a></li>                    
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div> 

    </header>

    <main>

        <section class="container">

            <div class="wrapper">

                <div class="col-12 divide">

                    <h1>Page Header</h1>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vitae augue ut nisl rutrum lacinia. In quis dapibus arcu. Praesent accumsan fermentum bibendum. Praesent ac efficitur arcu, et sodales mi. Vestibulum venenatis turpis ut pretium aliquet.</p>

                </div>

                <article class="grid col-12 bp1-col-6 bp3-col-4 half-divide">
                    <a href="page/page.html">
                        <img src="image.jpg" title="Image Name" alt="Image Name">
                        <h2>Image Name</h2>
                    </a> 
                </article>

                <article class="grid col-12 bp1-col-6 bp3-col-4 half-divide">
                    <a href="page/page.html">
                        <img src="image.jpg" title="Image Name" alt="Image Name">
                        <h2>Image Name</h2>
                    </a> 
                </article>

                <article class="grid col-12 bp1-col-6 bp3-col-4 half-divide">
                    <a href="page/page.html">
                        <img src="image.jpg" title="Image Name" alt="Image Name">
                        <h2>Image Name</h2>
                    </a> 
                </article>

                <article class="grid col-12 bp1-col-6 bp3-col-4 half-divide">
                    <a href="page/page.html">
                        <img src="image.jpg" title="Image Name" alt="Image Name">
                        <h2>Image Name</h2>
                    </a> 
                </article>                          

            </div>

        </section>

    </main>

    <footer>

        <div class="container">

            <nav>
                <a href="">Secondary Nav</a>
                <a href="">Secondary Nav</a>
            </nav>

            <p>Copyright Statement</p>

        </div>

    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the document outline with this code.

[image]

In the outline, there are a number of 'Untitled Sections', which are the header, main and footer. Is it okay that these are 'untitled' without a heading tag? I don't see how a heading tag could be used within these sections, unless it was hidden?

I have used the 'section' element to wrap the body, with the article elements within, as these are related to the h1 header and text. Is this correct use of the 'section' element?

Comment: It typically includes a heading, but if you identify it with other ways, it will also work as well. You just have to make it absolutely clear that it is the header and footer.

Comment: @DarthCadeus Thanks for the reply! In this case, my example is correct? How would it be absolutely clear that an item is a header or a footer?